# Want to use many ajax call in one document ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to make a page that has a pagination function and a search function.

The goal is to make a website that works like:

1. When the page is open, the client requests all the data from server and displays the data
2. When a user wants to search, a user can put any word inside the search tab and after a user presses the search button, the client requests the search to the server and gets all the results like the word and displays with pagination

I have tried to make multiple document ready functions and it didn't work.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var = XXX

//    The first ajax call when opening the page

$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/product/getAll",
  async: true,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    XXX
  }
});

//    The code when search button is pressed

$('productSearchBtn').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/product/getProduct",
    async: true,
    data: {
      productName: $('productSearchName').val()
    },
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      XXX
    }
  });
});


//    Function for generating table

function generate_table() {
  XXX
}

//    function for applying pagination

function apply_pagination() {
  XXX
}
});
}
});
```

All this code is in one `<script></script>` section. Sorry for not showing all the code because of posting restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your question for us to help you. The description of the errors and question also needs to be more specific. In the meantime, I've added some comments to:

- help eliminate a few possible errors
- narrow down where the code might be related to what I think you want to do
- possibly help with future coding

```js
//OXi: named functions can be declared before $(document).ready()

//Function for generating table
function generate_table() {
  //XXX
}

//function for applying pagination
function apply_pagination() {
  //XXX
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //var = XXX //OXi: commenting this out since it's not used and messes with tidy code; proper delcaration would have a variable name, use quotes for strings, and close with a semi-colon

  //The first ajax call when opening the page
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/product/getAll", //OXi: "http://localhost:8080" can be removed because any path starting with "/" is automatically fetched from localhost webroot
    async: true, //OXi: not needed, true by default
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      //XXX //OXi: if your page does not load or paginate correctly, it could be because of the code here
    }
  });

  //The code when search button is pressed
  $('productSearchBtn').click(function() { //OXi: is productSearchButton a class or id? Class needs a period in front. Id needs a hashtag in front. ".on('click', function()" is the recommended style for assigning event handlers in jQuery.
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/product/getProduct",
      async: true,
      data: {
        productName: $('productSearchName').val() //OXi: is productSearchName a class or id?
      },
      async: true, //OXi: duplicate parameter, still not necessary even the first time
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        //XXX //OXi: if your search is not working correctly, it could be because of the code here
      }
    });
  });

});

//OXi: extraneous closures below here, possibly from other code that was deleted?
//}
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've found out that I didnt put # at the front of id. It caused the event not getting fired.